# How to disable ads with AndroidBillingLibrary?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob

I'm using [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) to implement in-app billing. Purchasing item should disable ads in all activities. But when I tested my app (at first item was "android.test.purchase" and then real item) happened following: after the purchase ads were disabled, but after restarting the application ads are shown up again.

Item is published in developer's console, when I purchased item with test account Google Play said that all is Ok.

Purchase button is located in the settings of my application. Here is part of the code:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity { 
    public final static String PUBLIC_KEY = "my public key";
    public final static String ANDROID_ADS_ITEM = "ads.buy"; 
    private AbstractBillingObserver billingObserver;

    ...

    @Override protected void onDestroy(){   
        BillingController.unregisterObserver(billingObserver);  
        super.onDestroy(); 
    }

    private void adsDisable(){  
        final Preference adsDisable = (Preference) findPreference("disableAds");
        billingObserver = new AbstractBillingObserver(this){    
            public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId, ResponseCode response){ 
            }

            public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId, PurchaseState state){
            }

            public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported){
                if(!supported)
                    adsDisable.setEnabled(false);
                else if(!billingObserver.isTransactionsRestored())
                    BillingController.restoreTransactions(PreferencesActivity.this); 
            }

            public void onSubscriptionChecked(boolean supported) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }       
        };

        BillingController.setConfiguration(new IConfiguration(){

            public String getPublicKey(){
                return PUBLIC_KEY;          
            }

            public byte[] getObfuscationSalt(){
                return new byte[]{ 41, -90, -116, -41, 66, -53, 122, -110, -127, -96, -88, 77, 127, 115, 1, 73, 57, 110, 48, -116 }; 
            }

        }); 

        BillingController.registerObserver(billingObserver);        
        BillingController.checkBillingSupported(this);

        adsDisable.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){ 
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
                BillingController.requestPurchase(PreferencesActivity.this, ANDROID_ADS_ITEM, true, null);
                return false;
            }
        });

        boolean purchased = BillingController.isPurchased(this, ANDROID_ADS_ITEM);
        if(purchased){ 
            adsDisable.setTitle(R.string.disableAdsYes_prefs);          adsDisable.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

And this is how I try to disable ads:

```
public class FirstActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    public final static String ANDROID_ADS_ITEM = "ads.buy";
    private AdView adView;
    LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
        String adId = "my ad id";

        boolean purchased = BillingController.isPurchased(this, ANDROID_ADS_ITEM);
        if(purchased){
             layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads);
            layout.removeView(layout);
        } else {
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adId);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
       }
    }
  ....
}
```

Please, help. And sorry for my English.

Comment: This is probably an issue with checking if the in-app purchase was made.  However, you should really move your adView initializion and the loadAd call inside of `if (purchased)`.  Otherwise, you're making tons of ad requests that never get shown, and adding unnecessary latency and data usage for your paid users.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag I tried to move the loadAd call inside of `if(purchased)` but I get the same result. But if at first I open "Settings" screen in my app and then open activities with ads then I get no ads. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you're initialising the library configuration (public key and salt) in your preference activity. This means that the library will not be properly configured until you open preferences. Quoting the README:

> Additionally, BillingController requires a
>   BillingController.IConfiguration instance from which the public key
>   required to validate signed messages and a salt to obfuscate
>   transactions are obtained. A good place to provide the configuration
>   is in the Application subclass.

In this case, when you're calling `isPurcharsed` in your *FirstActivity* the billing controller doesn't have a salt to unobfuscate the database.

Check out [DungeonsRedux](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/tree/master/DungeonsRedux) for an example of setting the configuration in the Application subclass.

Comment: Thank you very much. How long I've tried to solve this problem and how it was simply.